# Using sources multiple times in a paper in different places--how to cite

Tags: citations, essay, mla, historical

I'm writing a paper for National History Day in my Social Studies class and am using MLA formatting. It occurred to me that I had a lot of differing information from some sources, such as a historical novel. How would I cite it if I put information from the same source into the paper in varying parts? Should I, instead, figure out a way to put it all together at once per source?

Answer (score 1):

The reference is abbreviated to the minimum required to clarify the source. For example, the work first referenced as:

7 Jane Doe, "Infinitely Anonymous," *Every Knows My Name*, 2nd ed., I Am Jane Doe (New York: Jane Doe Publishing, 2016) 42-43

on the second and subsequent reference would become either:

8 Doe 45  (if you use only one book by that author, or)

8 Doe, Everyone 45 (if you use multiple books by the same author.)

It used to be customary to use "Ibid." (short for the latin for "in the same place") or sometimes "op. cit." ("in the same place") for a subsequent reference, but I understand that the MLA no longer recommends that.

You might want to check college and university websites, which frequently have 'how-to' instructions on whichever kind of citation they use. MLA is common enough that you should be able to find a number of places.